# Too many bad command: outbound emails with Haraka

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, sendmail, haraka

When I trying to send email with `haraka` and `swaks` I get following error:

```
521 Too many bad commands
```

I execute `swaks` with following arguments:

```
swaks -f from@domain.com -t myemail@domain.com -s localhost -p 587 -au matt -ap pass
```

File `config/auth_flat_file.ini`:

```
[core]
methods=LOGIN

[users]
matt=pass
```

`swaks` gives me following output

```
=== Trying localhost:587...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 server ESMTP Haraka 2.5.0 ready
 -> EHLO server
<-  250-server Hello Unknown [127.0.0.1], Haraka is at your service.
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-SIZE 500000
<-  250 AUTH LOGIN
 -> AUTH LOGIN
<-  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
 -> bWF0dA==
<** 521 Too many bad commands
*** No authentication type succeeded
 -> QUIT
*** Remote host closed connection unexpectedly.
```

I used [this manual](https://haraka.github.io/manual/tutorials/SettingUpOutbound.html) to setting up Haraka for outbound emails.
In which can be error and how I can solve and avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is next:

Edit file `max_unrecognized_commands` - put biggest number than default (for example 20) and run `swaks` with following arguments:

`swaks --to user@domain.com --server localhost --port 587 -au matt -ap test --from notify@someserver.com`